# Configurable products showing below out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, category, configurable-product, position

I've just added some new configurable products to a category. They do show up but the problem is that they show up after the out of stock items. Everything in the category is sorted by best value which is the same for other categories but I don't have the same problem such as this one.

Comment: @user72958 please check below configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First check your back-end configuration:

```
Login to Admin -> System -> configuration -> Left side nav (Catalog) -> Inventory -> Set (Display Out of Stock Products) No.
```